# JavaScript Background Color Toggle

Tags: javascript

[image]

I have this simple function that is just simply supposed to toggle the background color of a button from aqua to red and back again.  However, when I call this function, all it does is change it to red and I'm not sure why.  I have looked at other similar examples on here and I feel like I'm doing it correctly.  Would love some help!

```
<button id = "button1" onclick="myFunction()">This is a button</button>

    button {
    background-color: Aqua;
}

function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor === "Aqua"){
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = "Red";
    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "I'm RED!!";
  } else { 
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = "Aqua";
    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "I'm back BABY!!";
  }  
}
```

Comment: `= "Aqua"` assigns, even in an `if` condition. The equality comparison operator is `===` (or `==`).

Comment: @Ry- That doesn't work

Comment: It is at least one thing wrong with your code. Please update it to show the fixed version if you’ve tried with it fixed.

Comment: @Ry- Updated it.  This just keeps the color Aqua

Comment: Try `console.log(document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor))`. It’ll show you what’s going on.

Comment: CSS colors are case sensitive. Use `aqua` and `red` instead of `Aqua` and `Red`.

Comment: I appreciate the input so far, but literally none of these suggestions are working

Comment: You tried logging the background color and it "didn't work"?

Comment: Your Codepen is missing a closing brace, so it’s different from the code in your question. Look in your browser console to see these kinds of errors (and the result of the `console.log`).

Comment: OH MY GOD!!  @Ry I'm sorry for being so stupid.  Yes, it was a damn closing brace.  It works now.  Thank you Ry and everyone else (and sorry!)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the first if statement should have lowercase aqua.. like the following

```
function myFunction() {
if (document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor === "aqua") {
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "I'm RED!!";
} else {
    document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor = "aqua";
    document.getElementById("button1").innerHTML = "I'm back BABY!!";
}
```

}

I found out by doing 
    console.log(document.getElementById("button1").style); and in the log you will have the object where you can unfold and find that the css selector is in lowercase,
also make red the same to avoid confusion.

hope it helps

Comment: Hey @Misha, this doesn't seem to change the color at all

Comment: @Justin Kindly share more of your code it can be more clear!
For me the button changes color on the second click..
Also Check if your javascript file is loaded correctly in a script tag in your html, 
you can do so by adding alert("Javascript Active") to you JS

Comment: I shared a screen shot for you.  I'm just using codepen

Comment: it was a damn closing brace.  I'm good now.  Thanks and sorry!

Comment: Glad it did help! Please consider @symlink s answer for a clean code.. select the right answer and good luck

Answer (score 0):

it works like this

```
if ($("#yourselector").css('background-color')=="rgb(220, 
20, 60)") alert("matched");
```

you need to convert name to red, green, blue components, you might use this tool

http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/hex-to-rgb/color-converter.php

Comment: This should be easier than your suggestion.  I'm looking for the simplest solution

Comment: This is the simplest one  u need RGB()

Answer (score 0):

The simplest wya to do this is to pass `this` into your `onclick()` function and use a ternary operator to determine the toggle state.

```js
function myFunction(btn) {
  const isRed = btn.style.backgroundColor === "red";
  btn.style.backgroundColor = isRed ? "aqua" : "red";
  btn.innerHTML = isRed ? "I'm back BABY!!" : "I'm RED!!";
}
```

```css
button {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="myFunction(this)">This is a button</button>
```